# Django 2.0 admin save functionality breaks when defining a custom manager

Tags: python, django, django-admin, jinja2

I am just starting to learn the Django framework, and I started with Django 2.0. I am creating just a simple site to mess around with, and I created a custom manager to get all objects that are in a "published" state. However, when I added this manager, it broke the admin's site Save/Edit/Delete functionality, and provides me with the error:

```
Manager isn't accessible via Post instances
```

Where the Post is the object that I have defined a custom manager for. (Forgive me if I am butchering the terminology). The traceback for this error isn't particularly easy to follow either.

Some code that will hopefully help.

Custom manager in my `models.py` file

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
```

Registering the managers in my Post class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

When I comment out the `published = PublishedManager()` line, all functionality is restored to the admin site. What is going wrong with the custom manager? Do I need to tell Django somewhere to use this in addition to the default manager? I definitely need to do some more learning, but this ones driving me crazy. Thanks all!

---

Traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/blog/post/add/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'taggit']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1554.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1483.             if form.is_valid():

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  179.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  174.             self.full_clean()

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  378.         self._post_clean()

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  407.             self.validate_unique()

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in validate_unique
  416.             self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in validate_unique
  952.         date_errors = self._perform_date_checks(date_checks)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _perform_date_checks
  1062.             date = getattr(self, unique_for)

File "/Users/jlahut/Programming/Python/django-blog/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in __get__
  178.             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/blog/post/add/
Exception Value: Manager isn't accessible via Post instances
```

Comment: Can you add the `traceback` ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sure, not a problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think adding `PublishedManager` causing the issue. You may be accessing the `PublishedManager` using  **Post** model instance

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Thanks for the feedback. What functions are called when the admin Save/Update/Delete operations are executed? I am just trying to narrow down the scope of what I have to debug. Could the issue possibly be in a template file? All other parts of the site work fine as is.